# How can you test Cytoscape Drag and Drop using Cypress?

Tags: cytoscape.js, cypress

I'm currently using Cytoscape.js 2.7.10 to create a set of nodes and edges created by drag and drop user actions. We are also using Cypress to create E2E tests but we haven't been able to test our drag and drop functionality following the Cypress recipe: https://docs.cypress.io/examples/examples/recipes.html#Drag-and-Drop.

How can you test drag and drop of Cytoscape nodes/edges using Cypress?